# Automatic login using beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am using beeline as a client to access hive databases. Every time I use beeline, it asks me for the connection URL, username and password. Is there a way to set these parameters in a configuration file and load it automatically instead of re-typing them for each login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM.

- [HiveServer2 Clients](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommandOptions) > about Beeline command-line arguments
- [alias (command) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) > about the `alias` built-in Linux shell command

So if your default shell is Bash and you add that line in your `~/.bashrc` config...

```
alias duh='/usr/bin/beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myhost:10000/" -n myname -p mypassword --fastConnect=true --showWarnings=true --force=true --showNestedErrs=true --headerInterval=20 --maxWidth=8192'
```

...on your next login you will be able to type `duh` and get a Beeline prompt.

Note that I added a full shitload of options that may, or may not, be interesting for you. Just in case you might want to read the manual after all.

Note also that the quotes around the URL are not really useful here, but if you ever add some extra URL options using the evil `;` character, then they will be required.

Answer (score 0):

you may put the below line in your .hiverc file

Loading beeline, the URL and providing your username & password in one command:
**

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2:// silver-server-hive.app.google.com:10000\ 
-n <yourname> -p <yourpassword> --incremental=true
```

**